# How do decimal remainders work in terms of long division?

Tags: arithmetic

I was taught long division a long time ago, and I had this question.
[image]
Simple enough so far.
But then, instead of writing the remainder, I was taught to turn the answer into a decimal by adding zeroes, like so.
[image]
And further more. [image]
I understand it has something to do with the numbers being tenths and hundredths, but I can't fully grasp it. How does this work?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathSE! The images seem a bit confusing, maybe try typing them out in MathJax? You can use this guide for reference: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Note that $22 = 22.0000000000...$

Comment: Um... what's your question exactly.  You just described long division correctly.  What about the description do you need clarified specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three significant figures of $22/7$ are the same as the first three significant figures of $2200/7$ $-$ just the position of the decimal point has changed. So you just have to 'pretend' that you are dividing $2200$ by $7$. And then $22000$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Blauheim44 Welcome to MSE! If you think this answer addresses your question, please click the green tick on the left to accept it. This both stimulates more people to give good answers, and helps those who come later to this question to find the correct answer quickly.

Comment: Hi Tony, (+1) for concise answer.

Comment: @Trebor, there _is_ no green tick on the left! Until the answer is accepted :-)

Comment: @TonyK  Oops, you caught me :P

Answer (score 1):

$22 = 3\times 7 + 1$ so $22 \div 7 = (21 + 1)\div 7 = 21\div 7 + 1 \div 7 = 3 + 1\div 7$.

That is $3$ and $1$ remainder.  That $1$ remainder must in turn be divided by $7$.  One way of doing that is to simply to use fractions and say $22 \div 7 = 3 \frac 17$.  This is sensible.  If we divide a $1$ into seven parts each part is $\frac 17$.

But how to do it in decimals? The issue is the same we still have $22 \div 7 = 3 + (1 \div 7)$ and we have to figure out what $1\div 7$ in decimals is.

Well.  $1$ can be written as $\frac {10}{10}$.  That is we divide $1$ into $10$ pieces and then divide these $10$ pieces by $7$.

We can think of it this way.  $1 \div 7 = \frac {10}{10} = 10\cdot \color{red}{\frac 1{10}}\div 7 = (10\div 7)\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}$

In a way... if you have $10 \color{red}{\ THINGS}$ and you divide them by $7$ you will have $10 \div 7 \color{red}{\ THINGS}$ and it doesn't matter what the $ \color{red}{\ THINGS}$ are.  The could be apples, they could be bricks. Or they could by $ \color{red}{\frac 1{10}}$s.

(In fact this is exactly how long division of *big* numbers work.  To do $822 \div 6$ you start by saying $822$ is $8$ hundreds plus some stuff.  $8\div 6$ is $1$ with $2$ remainder so I have $1$ hundred and then $2$ hundreds extra.  So $822\div 6 = (8\times 100 + 22)\div 6 = (8\div 6)\times 100 + (22\div 6) = 1\times 100 + (2\times 100 + 22)\div 6= 100 + (222\div 6)$.  Then you do the same for $222\div 6$.  That's $22$ tens plus some stuff; so you divide $22$ by $6$ to get $3$ tens and $4$ remaining tens and so on.... the only difference here is was are using $\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}$s and not $\color{red}{100}$s.)

And so $(10\div 7) = 1 R 3$ so we get $1$ of these $\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}$s with $3$ of these $\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}$s remaining.

So.... what have we got so far?

$22 \div 7 = (21 + 1)\div 7 = 21\div 7 + 1 \div 7 = 3 + 1\div 7=$

$3 + (10\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}\div 7 = 3 + (10\div 7)\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}=$

$3 + (1 \text{with 3 remaining})\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}= 3 +1\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}} + (3\div 7)\cdot\color{red}{\frac 1{10}}=$

$3 + \frac 1{10} + (\frac 3{10}\div 7)$.

Now we we can rewrite $\frac 3{10}$ as $\frac {30}{100}$ and we now have $30$ of small $\color{orange}{\frac 1{100}}$ pieces.  We do the same thing over again.

We have $30$ of these pieces and we divide the $30$ pieces by $7$ and we will have $4$ groups of $7$ of these pieces and $2$ remaining.

$22\div 7 = (21 + 1)\div 7 =$

$3 + 1\div 7 = 3 + \frac{10}{10}\div 7 =$

$3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + \frac {3}{10}\div 7 =$

$3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + \frac {30}{100}\div 7 = $

$3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + 4\cdot \frac 1{100} + \frac {2}{100} \div 7 =$

$3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + 4\cdot \frac 1{100} + \frac {20}{1000}\div 7 =$

$3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + 4\cdot \frac 1{100} + 2\cdot \frac 1{1000} + \frac 6{1000}\div 7 = $

$....$

As we can write $\frac 1{10}, \frac 1{100}, etc$ as $0.1$ or $0.01$ or etc we get

$22\div 7 =3 + 1\cdot \frac 1{10} + 4\cdot \frac 1{100} + 2\cdot \frac 1{1000} +....= 3 + 0.1 + 0.04 + 0.0002 + ..... = 3.142......$